# An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in UWP-Weather-App.exe but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, api, xaml, uwp

I've been following a tutorial of a UWP Weather application that uses an API key.

I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

This is the method it happens in, at the line that begins with `RootObject`:

```cs
namespace UWP_Weather_App
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RootObject myWeather = await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(20.0, 30.0);
            ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + myWeather.main.temp + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's happening on that line? You're not accessing any methods/properties of an object there (I'm assuming `GetWeather` is a static method). The second line, however, has many possible causes for that error.

Comment: Isn't the OpenWeatherMapProxy null?

Comment: `public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
            {
                var http = new HttpClient();
                var response = await  http.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&appid=4440e0954b4016d22acceaf9d4be72fd&units=metric");
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
                return data;
            }
`

This is whats inside OpenWeatherMapProxy. Sorry about the foormatting of the code, I know its horrendous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I'd suppose you are following this [UWP Weather  tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-057-UWP-Weather--Introduction). I used your code with this tutorial's [source code](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10/tree/master/UWP-057/UWP-057) and reproduced your issue.

The `System.NullReferenceException` error occurred at the line `ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + myWeather.main.temp + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;`
[image]

This is because the URL you've used in `GetWeather` method is not right. The result returned by this URL doesn't contain weather information and when it is deserialized to `RootObject`, most properties will be null.
[image]

To retrieve current weather data by geographic coordinates, we can use following API:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}
```

And starting from 9 October 2015 this API requires a valid APPID for access. For more info, please see [Call current weather data for one location](http://openweathermap.org/current#geo) and [How to use API key in API call](http://openweathermap.org/appid#use).

So we can change `GetWeather` method like following to fix this error.

```
public async static Task<RootObject> GetWeather(double lat, double lon)
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync($"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={APIKEY}&units=metric");
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    return data;
}
```

Please note that I tried with your API key, but I got `401 Invalid API key` error, so please make sure you are using the right key. And also, we need to change `Main.pressure` and `Wind.deg`'s type to `double` as their value are not `int`. If we don't change the type, we may get `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException` while deserialization.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what was wrong. Thanks for taking the time to help. One last question, when I run the application it says the location is Earth rather than my city and country(Galway, Ireland). Would you have any idea how to correct that?

Comment: @Lynskey08 What’s the coordinates you've used? I tried with following API call: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Galway,ie&appid={APIKEY}`, it works well.

Comment: I've just after updating the coordinates to coordinates of my general location. Thank you so much that code worked perfectly. You're a gentleman for taking the time to help me. It even printed Galway in Irish for me :)